# Does incremental GC preclude using the Cheney algorithm?

Tags: garbage-collection

I've been using the Cheney two-space GC algorithm for many years, but I'm ready to graduate to a generational-style collector.  I've read the 'beltway' paper, and I have the Jones book.  I'm trying to understand the implications of doing a 'partial' GC - i.e., collecting only a portion of a a generation/subspace.  My plan is to implement the beltway collector.

If I understand it correctly, doing a partial collection precludes using the Cheney algorithm, because that algorithm assumes that you are copying everything that you visit.  If I collect only a window within a subspace (an 'increment' in the terms used by the beltway paper), then I must visit some records (in other increments in the same belt) that I will not be copying.

More context: this is for a functional language, a Scheme dialect using an ML-style static type system.  I'm currently using runtime tags (so I can easily tell pointer from non-pointer), but I intend to move toward a more tagless scheme using compile-time information.  This is another motivator away from Cheney, since a recursive descent of some kind will be necessary while traversing the type graph of each pointer.